# WMQ: Distributing MQ readers over several machines

Tags: c#, transactions, ibm-mq

I am using WMQ to access an IBM WebSphere MQ on a mainframe - using c#.

We are considering spreading out our service on several machines, and we then need to make sure that two services on two different machines cannot read/get the same MQ message at the same time.

My code for getting messages is this:

```
var connectionProperties = new Hashtable();

const string transport = MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT;
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, transport);
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, mqServerIP);
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, mqServerPort);
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, mqChannelName);

_mqManager = new MQQueueManager(mqManagerName, connectionProperties);

var queue = _mqManager.AccessQueue(_queueName, MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
var queueMessage = new MQMessage {Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING};
var queueGetMessageOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions {Options = MQC.MQGMO_WAIT, WaitInterval = 2000};
queue.Get(queueMessage, queueGetMessageOptions);

queue.Close();
_mqManager.Commit();
return queueMessage.ReadString(queueMessage.MessageLength);
```

Is WebSphere MQ transactional by default, or is there something I need to change in my configuration to enable this?

Or - do I need to ask our mainframe guys to do some of their magic?

Thx

Comment: I'm not sure what MQ is all about but I assume it's similar to Microsoft's Message Queuing.   All you really need to avoid collisions is Unique IDs and a way to resolve conflicts.  If there are two message read/altered at the same time it is up to the Host application to apply the business rules that matter.  This is no different than any other Asynchronous operation whereby it is Always the responsibility of the Host to say what's wrong and the client to apply the appropriate work flow when the condition happens.  That workflow must be designed.

Comment: This is why many of us out here love Entity Framework because it has all of this type of thing built into it.  Entity Framework is not a messaging service; however, one could argue that it serves the same purpose.

Comment: John - for reference unless you go out of your way, by default every MQ message is given a unique msgid. However see my answer for a more precise answer to the raised question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wish I'd found this sooner because the accepted answer is incomplete.  MQ provides once and only once delivery of messages as described in the other answer and IBM's documentation.  If you have many clients listening on the same queue, MQ will deliver only one copy of the message.  This is uncontested.

That said, MQ, or any other async messaging for that matter, must deal with session handling and ambiguous outcomes.  The affect of these factors is such that any async messaging application should be designed to gracefully handle dupe messages.

Consider an application putting a message onto a queue.  If the `PUT` call receives a `2009 Connection Broken` response, it is unclear whether the connection failed before or after the channel agent received and acted on the API call.  The application, having no way to tell the difference, must put the message again to assure it is received.  Doing the `PUT` under syncpoint can result in a `2009` on the `COMMIT` (or equivalent return code in messaging transports other than MQ) and the app doesn't know if the `COMMIT` was successful or if the `PUT` will eventually be rolled back.  To be safe it must `PUT` the message again.

Now consider the partner application receiving the messages.  A `GET` issued outside of syncpoint that reaches the channel agent will permanently remove the message from the queue, even if the channel agent cannot then deliver it.  So use of transacted sessions ensures that the message is not lost.  But suppose that the message has been received and processed and the `COMMIT` returns a `2009 Connection Broken`.  The app has no way to know whether the message was removed during the `COMMIT` or will be rolled back and delivered again.  At the very least the app can avoid losing messages by using transacted sessions to retrieve them, but can not guarantee to never receive a dupe.

This is of course endemic to all async messaging, not just MQ, which is why the JMS specification directly address it.  The situation is addressed in all versions but in the [JMS 1.1 spec](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/docs-136352.html) look in section *4.4.13 Duplicate Production of Messages* which states:

> If a failure occurs between the time a client commits its work on a
>   Session and the commit method returns, the client cannot determine if
>   the transaction was committed or rolled back. The same ambiguity
>   exists when a failure occurs between the non-transactional send of a
>   PERSISTENT message and the return from the sending method.
>
> It is up to a JMS application to deal with this ambiguity. In some
>   cases, this may cause a client to produce functionally duplicate
>   messages.
>
> A message that is redelivered due to session recovery is not
>   considered a duplicate message.

If it is critical that the application receive one and only one copy of the message, use 2-Phase transactions.  The transaction manager and XA protocol will provide very strong (but still not absolute) assurance that only one copy of the message will be processed by the application.

The behavior of the messaging transport in delivering one and only one copy of a given message is a measure of the reliability of the transport.  By contrast, the behavior of an application which relies on receipt of one and only one copy of the message is a measure of the reliability of the application.

Any duplicate messages received from an IBM MQ transport are almost certainly going to be due to the application's failure to use XA to account for the ambiguous outcomes inherent in async messaging and not a defect in MQ.  Please keep this in mind when the Production version of the application chokes on its first duplicate message.

On a related note, if Disaster Recovery is involved, the app must also gracefully recover from lost messages, or else find a way to [violate the laws of relativity](https://t-rob.net/2012/10/24/thoughts-on-disaster-recovery/).

Answer (score 4):

Unless you actively BROWSE the message (ie read it but leave it there with no locks), only one getter will ever be able to 'get' the message. Even without transactionality, MQ will still only deliver the message once... but once delivered its gone

MQ is not transactional 'by default' - you need to get with GMO_SYNCPOINT (MQ transactions) and commit at the connection (MQQueueManager level) if you want transactionality (or integrate with .net transactions is another option)

If you use syncpoint then one getter will get the message, the other will ignore it, but if you subsequently have an issue and rollback, then it is made available to any getter (as you would want). It is this scenario where you might see a message twice, but thats because you aborted the transaction and hence asked for it to be put back to how it was before the get.

Comment: thank you - as I read your reply, I do not need to do anything else to ensure that MQ will only deliver each message once - and that MQ will ensure that whenever a client is busy reading/getting a message from MQ, another instance will not start reading the same message. I will also, based on your reply, need to refactor my code to allow rolling back if something goes wrong (I will look into this at a later time). Thanks again :-)